# Lyrics to Electro-Light "Night Shines" (meaning and corrections)

Tags: lyrics

[Electro-Light ft. Nathan Brumley - Night Shines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PY2fvQA0H0)

There is a [lyric video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqz8Hr7Sz54) of this song, however I think some of the lyrics presented on the lyrical may be off or something that's just confusing to me. Below are what I think the correct lyrics are:

```
When the feeling's gone and I am left alone
With a trace of the night
On the way back down from the sky where you left my soul
Can you help me fly?

I can't resist
'Cause you have got
A hold on me
And all these thoughts
When you are here
You light up the dark skies
'Till even the night shines

You take my life
And light every side 
You fade the dark
Inside, 'till even the night shines

'Till even the night shines

'Till even the night shines
```

What do these lyrics mean? The second verse looks like it's expressing love, but in particular, what are they trying to say in the first verse? Especially the part that says "you left my soul in the sky".

Also, could you tell me what you think the correct lyrics are? Or where you think they may be different from what I came up with?

Comment: "You light up the dark's eyes (dark sides?)" I'd bet that's "You light up the dark skies."

Answer (score 2):

Lyric interpretations are always subjective, but I'd venture that this one is talking about how the narrator feels after a date with a new love interest ends. While he was out on the date, he felt so euphoric, it was like he was flying high up in the sky.  But now that [she] has gone home, he's coming down off that cloud (AKA feeling of being on a natural high).

They were probably out at nighttime, so that gives all the night imagery. Even though it was dark outside, [she] was like a bright source of light as long as they were together.

Comment: Do you think the odd IV-V-II-IV chord progression might be of any significance?